# Can Python optimize my function inputs to get a target value?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, convergence

I have been trying to locate a method similar to Excel's Solver where I can target a specific value for a function to converge on. I do not want a minimum or maximum optimization.

For example, if my function is: 

 `f(x) = A^2 + cos(B) - sqrt(C)` 


I want f(x) = 1.86, is there a Python method that can iterate a solution for A, B, and C to get as close to 1.86 as possible? (given an acceptable error to target value?)

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html and https://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a root finding algorithm for your problem. Only a small *transformation* required. Find roots for *g(x)*:

`g(x) = A^2 + cos(B) - sqrt(C) - 1.86`

***Using*** `scipy.optimize.root`, *Refer*  [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

# extra two 0's as dummy equations as root solves a system of equations 
# rather than single multivariate equation
def func(x):                                        # A,B,C represented by x ndarray
    return [np.square(x[0]) + np.cos(x[1]) - np.sqrt(x[2]) - 1.86, 0, 0]

result = optimize.root(func , x0 = [0.1,0.1,0.1])
x = result.x
A, B, C = x                       
x
# array([ 1.09328544, -0.37977694,  0.06970678])
```

*you can now check your solution:*

```
np.square(x[0]) + np.cos(x[1]) - np.sqrt(x[2])

# 1.8600000000000005
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for your help :)